# How do nested bool queries work ? Is there a single wrapper that can disable nesting on all the nested levels?

Tags: elasticsearch

If you wrap bool query in constant Score Query does it calculate score for internal queries. Is there another easy way to disable scoring?

Hi I have an update so I have a query where no scoring is required, so I wrote it in two forms and did load testing with 10000 documents.

Following are the two structures of query with which I did load testing:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "must": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  bool:.......
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the second one is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  bool:.......
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I found was that the first query took almost as double time as the second query. I would like to know why this happened?

Also, do the internal bool queries inside filter in first example run in query context or filter context?

I have read elastic search documentation and cannot find references or details on how it works internally.

Thanks, in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query can have two type of context in elastic search. `Query` context and `filter` context. Query context tells how well a document matches the query i.e. it calculates score whereas filter context tells whether a document matches the query and no scoring is done.

To answer your question, if you don't want scoring for bool query simply put it in filter context. More info on query context can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)

Comment: Hi Nishant, I have been through this. But it does not answer the question of  nested bool query. I performed load test on 10000 documents and the 'took' in response almost varies by 100% for following two examples, can you explain why this happened.?

Comment: Can you share the data you are using to perform load test and also the exact queries so that I can try the same.

Comment: No I can't share the data as it is confidential

Comment: Though can you answer this question:

 do the internal bool queries inside filter in first example run in query context or filter context?

Comment: Anything inside `filter` block is filter context. You need not put every bool query in filter context. Scoring may not be the reason for difference in the performance of the two queries. Try adding `explain: true` to understand the execution of query and you may also come to know why one query is taking more time.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Caching is probably why. See the documentation: "Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch, to speed up performance."

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html